# What does runtime.memclrNoHeapPointers do?

Tags: go, profiling

I am profiling a library and see that a function called `runtime.memclrNoHeapPointers` is taking up about 0.82seconds of the cpu-time.

What does this function do, and what does this tell me about the memory-usage of the library i am profiling?

The output, for completeness:

```
File: gribtest.test
Type: cpu
Time: Feb 12, 2019 at 8:27pm (CET)
Duration: 5.21s, Total samples = 5.11s (98.15%)
Showing nodes accounting for 4.94s, 96.67% of 5.11s total
Dropped 61 nodes (cum <= 0.03s)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     1.60s 31.31% 31.31%      1.81s 35.42%  github.com/nilsmagnus/grib/griblib.(*BitReader).readBit
     1.08s 21.14% 52.45%      2.89s 56.56%  github.com/nilsmagnus/grib/griblib.(*BitReader).readUint
     0.37s  7.24% 59.69%      0.82s 16.05%  encoding/binary.(*decoder).value
     0.35s  6.85% 66.54%      0.35s  6.85%  runtime.memclrNoHeapPointers
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/?m=all#memclrNoHeapPointers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> func memclrNoHeapPointers(ptr unsafe.Pointer, n uintptr)
>
> memclrNoHeapPointers clears n bytes starting at ptr.
>
> Usually you should use typedmemclr. memclrNoHeapPointers should be
>   used only when the caller knows that *ptr contains no heap pointers
>   because either:
>
> 1. *ptr is initialized memory and its type is pointer-free.
> 2. *ptr is uninitialized memory (e.g., memory that's being reused
>
> for a new allocation) and hence contains only "junk".
>
> in memclr_*.s go:noescape

See https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9e277f7d554455e16ba3762541c53e9bfc1d8188/src/runtime/stubs.go#L78

This is part of the garbage collector. [You can see the declaration here.](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/75798e8ada7fcb286f633618ac2f55ad5240ed97/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/builtin/runtime.go)

The specifics of what it does are CPU dependent. [See the various memclr_*.s files in the runtime for implmentation](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/50bd1c4d4eb4fac8ddeb5f063c099daccfb71b26/src/runtime)

This does seem like a long time in the GC, but it's hard to say something about the memory usage of the library with just the data you've shown I think.

Comment: The library parses binary files into structs while doing some decompression on the data, so I guess a bit of gc is necessary to read all the data into arrays and then decompress it further into structs. Thanks for the answer!